# Woocommerce AJAX navigation

Tags: ajax, html, wordpress, navigation, woocommerce

My client would like to include an audio player playing background music which doesn't stop during the navigation.

Developpement of the theme is over (based on an existing Woocomerce theme).

I am looking for a great (& if possible quick) way to make the pages loading via AJAX requests in order to keep audio playing in the background.

I do not want to download another "AJAX Woocomerce theme" and restart development since the beginning so what are the other options ? I made a few search for an extension that would fit my needs but can't seem to find one at all.

Answer (score 0):

Before you look into this, try and take a look at this Ajax with wordpress turtorial to understand how this works. [woocommerce] [ajax] https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/using-ajax-with-wordpress/. Its not a quik fix, BUt you also have plugiins liek https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-ajax-page-loader/ that might work.